# Concatenating two dataframes on common index, is there more efficient way to do this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two dataframes, first one is:

```
      col1   col2   col3   
1     14      2     6     
2     12      3     3     
3     9       4     2
```

Second one is:

```
      col4   col5   col6   
2     14      2     6     
3     12      3     3
```

I want to concatenate them and get the index values from second one and row values from the first one.

The result will be like this:

```
      col1   col2   col3   
2     12      3     3     
3     9       4     2
```

My solution was `pd.concat([df2, df1, axis=1)]).drop(df2, axis=1)` but I believe there is more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use index from df2 with loc function on df1:

```
df1.loc[df2.index]
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2    col3
2   12      3       3
3   9       4       2
```

Comment: I think that this question is for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ not stack overflow

Comment: I have no say in where this question goes

Comment: @Theshape  this looks good as per SO standards. Read: [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @dm2 but isn't stack overflow for answering mistakes and not reviewing code??

Comment: Answering mistakes sounds like a code review (afaik stackoverlow is for answering specific question in programming, and I've seen several similar questions). Either way, there's nothing I can do to move the question that you can't.